# "Pro-attitude" Definition

Tags: meaning, nouns, synonyms

What does the word **pro-attitude** mean in the following sentence:

> Intentions are pro-attitudes, directed towards some future state of
> affairs.
>
> [reference](http://books.google.com/books?id=RBoA_7kogfIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22mobile+intention+recognition%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8feHUOXpBvC80QGJrIHQCg&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22Intentions%20are%20pro-attitudes%2C%20directed%20towards%20some%20future%20state%20of%20affairs.%22&f=false)

I couldn't find this word  in the dictionaries.

Could you suggest a synonym for this word or explain it in some other words?

Comment: Could you tell us the source for where you got the sentence?

Comment: @MattЭллен - It's now added to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"[A pro-attitude is an agent 's mental attitude](http://www.blackwellreference.com/public/tocnode?id=g9781405106795_chunk_g978140510679517_ss1-271) directed toward an action under a certain description. Such attitudes include wants, desires , urges, moral views, aesthetic principles, and economic prejudices. Such a set of mental attitudes, together with the agent's belief that acting in a certain way promotes what the agent wants or values, form the primary reason for an agent to act in that way."

In simple terms, a pro-attitude is an urge or desire that drives an action.

[Read a discussion of it here.](http://endsofthought.blogspot.sg/2008/07/davidson-on-pro-attitudes-evaluative.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It seems that you work in this area. Can I ask an out of scope question about "intention recognition in computing environments"?

Comment: @Ezati you should visit [cogsci.se], they'll love questions like that.

Comment: @MattЭллен - Unfortunately they don't love it:http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/1775/how-cognitive-science-defines-intention

Comment: Oh. Sorry about that. It sounded perfect!

Comment: I think this expression is best understood by inserting a space between "pro-" and "attitude." Using that spelling would save a lot of confusion, alas...